# ModSecurity 912-DOS-PROTECTION rule doesn't work

Tags: apache, mod-security

I'm using mod_security 2.9.2 with OWASP Core Rule Set version 3.3 running under Apache 2.4.

To try to stop simple DOS attacks, I've enabled the rule 912-DOS-PROTECTION, but it's not having any effect.

To enable the rule, I added the following to my `mod_security.conf` as suggested by the documentation in `REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf`:

```
SecAction \
"id:900700,phase:1,nolog,pass,t:none,\
setvar:'tx.dos_burst_time_slice=3',\
setvar:'tx.dos_counter_threshold=50',\
setvar:'tx.dos_block_timeout=600',\
setvar:'tx.static_extensions=/.jpg/ /.jpeg/ /.png/ /.gif/ /.js/ /.css/ /.ico/'"
```

This rule should activate when the server gets more than 50 non-image requests over a 3-second period.

However, it doesn't have any effect on my server, and does not stop any incoming requests.

To simulate real traffic, I use the utility `ab` to create connections to my server.

For example, here's a test that uses 60 concurrent connections over a period of 6 seconds:

```
ab -c 60 -t 6 "[URL]"
```

I get the following output from a sample run:

```
Concurrency Level:      60
Time taken for tests:   6.018 seconds
Complete requests:      611
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      110954039 bytes
```

It appears **all requests** were successful. This is not what should happen. I would expect that, shortly after the test starts running, the DOS detection would be tripped, and subsequent requests would be blocked.

My `modsec_audit.log` does occasionally log some messages while I run these tests (but not on every run). Here's an example:

```
Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 2 at IP:dos_burst_counter. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf"] [line "269"] [id "912170"] [msg "Potential Denial of Service (DoS) Attack from [IP] - # of Request Bursts: 2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.1"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "attack-dos"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/227/469"]
Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 273] [level 3] [client IP] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator GE matched 2 at IP:dos_burst_counter. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf"] [line "269"] [id "912170"] [msg "Potential Denial of Service (DoS) Attack from [IP] - # of Request Bursts: 2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.1"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "attack-dos"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/227/469"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "Yu-n6NGj9kT3clHjZubuCQAAAM0"]
Apache-Handler: proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost
```

However, these messages appear only rarely, and it doesn't seem they indicate that any block occurred, as they are associated with log entries that show `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. I assume this means that the request was successful, even if the threshold for DOS detection was reached.

Does anyone know how I can get the simple mod_security DOS protection to work as documented?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what is the `SecRuleEngine` value in your modsecurity.conf?

Comment: It's set to On. All other mod_security OWASP rules work as expected. Only the DOS detection does not.

Comment: I'll check that on my machine soon.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but I couldn't. See my results here: https://gist.github.com/airween/89a8e866d45e2fcca609381f15041f6a. As you can see, about 50% of requests were failed. For more investigation I need more info, eg. configs (modsecurity.cong, crs-setup.conf, ...). You might open an issue on CRS's Github page: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset, and share the files there.

Comment: Thank you very much for running that test. It appears you are using paranoia level 2. In my crs_setup.conf, the only change I made was to reduce the verbosity of the logs. I haven't set any value for paranoia level, so it appears I'm on level 1 by default. As for mod_security.conf, I have left everything at its default, and included only the OWASP ruleset with "IncludeOptional modsecurity.d/activated_rules/*.conf" and the DOS rule with id 900700, as in the above snippet. Is it normal that DOS detection would not work at paranoia level 1? Thanks!

Comment: No, I'm using PL4 in that config. But I think the DOS detection rules shouldn't depend on PL. I'll check the behavior on PL1, and will be back.

Comment: Ah, okay. I saw in your log entries `[tag "paranoia-level/2"]`, so I assumed that was the level you were using. My understanding is the level 1 should trigger after the second "burst" of activity, whereas level 2 triggers after the first burst detected. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have set my config to use PL1, see the updated gist: https://gist.github.com/airween/89a8e866d45e2fcca609381f15041f6a#file-ab_out_pl1-txt. As you can see, DOS protection still works. Just one important thing: in crs-setup.conf, I've set the PL two places, see the gist: https://gist.github.com/airween/89a8e866d45e2fcca609381f15041f6a#file-crs-setup-pl1-conf. See the rule 900000 and 900001.

Comment: That's interesting. My crs-setup.conf is the default -- no changes. The two rules 900000 and 900001 are commented out, but the documentation says that PL1 is the default. I've been able to reproduce on two different VMs, both running RHEL 8.6. As a workaround, I was able to achieve what I want with mod_qos. I would have preferred to stick with mod_security rather than using a new module, but it will not trigger on the DOS rule. I could file a big report, but it sounds like the OWASP team is removing DOS completely from future versions of the ruleset.

Comment: Can you try that to modify these two rules in your crs-setup.conf? Just for curiosity... Yes, if you don't set the explicit PL value, then later CRS sets up for itself in 901-INITIALIZATION, in rules 901120 and 901125.

You can set up your debug.log with some higher value (9 is the max), then you can follow what happens with your rules and variables.

Just for the record: I'm member of CRS team (this is a Dev-on-duty program). We do not remove completely the DOS rules, but reorganized many rules. From the 4.0, those are available as plugins: https://github.com/coreruleset/plugin-registry.

Comment: I've uncommented both of those rules in crs-setup.conf and restarted Apache, but I still get the same result after using `ab`. No requests are blocked. I also set the `SecDebugLogLevel` to 5, just to see what would happen. This gives me a massive debug log, but I'm not sure how to interpret those results. I've pasted a snippet here: https://controlc.com/725f0619. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this part of your debug log contains only the results of rules 959NNN. Could you share the rules with id 912NNN, from file REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf?

Comment: Does this log snippet help?  https://controlc.com/0b99960e

Comment: Unfortunately no. In this snippet, the rule 912140 exists once. This means, the DOS activation does not work in that moment. The protection activating when the counter reaches the value you have set, so with these vales above more log parts need. Perhaps you should decrease the threshold value to some extremely low, and increase the slice value. Then try to run ab again with some lower value.

Comment: I've just run the test again and have snipped the last 2000 lines from the debug log. Since it's from the end of the log, in theory this should show that requests are being blocked. Of course it isn't -- but it should be :-) Hopefully this will contain enough to be useful: https://controlc.com/ecfbbd3d Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it looks better. Let me check this, but may be I will be able to do that only later, eg. on the next week.